# Como o FireMonkey(Delphi) compila para Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Efetuei algumas pesquisas mas não obtive bons resultados, a pasta do projeto fica aparentemente igual a um projeto comum do Delphi ou C++!

- VCL - Delphi
- FMX - Firemonkey

Observem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com exceção da pasta *Android*, onde contem algumas sub-pastas, é possível encontrar o APK já compilado, arquivos `.XLM`, e diversos arquivos com a extensão `.SO` (essa não faço ideia do que seja).

Programar para **Android** ou **IPhone** nessa IDE é a mesma coisa que programar para Delphi!

Então pergunto, como essa IDE compila para Android?
Seria pura Abstração de Classes Java?

**EDIT**

> A possibilidade de desenvolver para Android, foi implementada na
>   versão XE5!
>   Para desenvolver Android com o RADStudio precisamos das seguintes ferramentas:
>
> Java Development Kit (**JDK**)
>
> Android Software Development Kit (**SDK**)
>
> Android Native Development Kit (**NDK**)

Comment: Usando um compilador para cada plataforma? Acho que não está claro exatamente o que você perguntou...

Comment: Ele usa o NDK, mas como eu não sei, mas tenha certeza que existe um passo intermediário em C ou Java, porque a Embarcadero prometeu código nativo pra todas as plataformas.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA Sim sim, já podemos desenvolver verdadeiramente nativo! Vou dar uma explorada por ae sobre a NDK e ver o que acontece!

Comment: @DarkHyudrA não tem passo intermediário... É um compilador diferente. Só isso.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Fonte? Tu tá dizendo que eles tem um NDK alterado? Porque o NDK é bem claro dizendo com que linguagens ele consegue funcionar. E se a Embarcadero tivesse feito um código milagroso que passa direto de delphi pra dpk, por que o NDK é algo necessário na compilação? Eu não sou nenhum mestre do Deplhi, mas eu não consigo ver como possa acontecer a geração do dpk sem um passo intermediário. É a mesma coisa com Haxe, haxe é compilado pra C que aí o código C é que é compilado pela NDK pra gerar o dpk.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA Fonte? Onde é que o NDK diz com que linguagens ele consegue funcionar e que não pode ser uma linguagem compilada diferente de C ou Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até onde deu para entender, basicamente é isto, ele abstrai as classes e compila o Apk (não tão simples assim).

---

**Traduzido de uma nota:**

*Desenvolvedores Delphi são amplamente protegidos contra a complexidade da NDK, já que o código usando o alto nível de abstração fornecida pela biblioteca de tempo de execução (RTL) e do quadro FireMonkey. Se isso é tudo que você precisa que eu deveria pensar que tudo ficará bem. Se você tem uma biblioteca Java você precisa chamar a partir da aplicação Delphi Android, você precisa usar JNI (Java Native Interface), que não é muito divertido.*

---

Outro ponto a salientar é que o FireMonkey emula controles visuais, como botões, listas etc. Os usuários podem não perceber, mas os componentes comportam exatamente como os controles nativos, mas isso é complicado de fazer perfeitamente.

A promessa da *Embarcadero* é que desenvolveríamos de forma nativa em relação ao código, mas não em relação aos controles que utiliza.

Aqui [podemos encontrar a documentação da NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

**VCL é incompatível com FireMonkey**

FireMonkey (FMX) e a biblioteca de componentes do Visual (VCL) não são compatíveis e não devem ser utilizados em conjunto no mesmo módulo. Isto quer dizer que um módulo deve ser exclusivamente um ou outro, quer FireMonkey ou VCL. A incompatibilidade é causado por diferenças quadro entre FireMonkey (FMX) e VCL.

No entanto, você pode:

Use uma biblioteca FireMonkey com uma aplicação de VCL, ou usar uma biblioteca VCL com uma aplicação FireMonkey, conforme descrito em bibliotecas compartilhadas para Mac OS X.
        Leia as orientações gerais para a conversão de uma aplicação VCL para FireMonkey em Convertendo de VCL para FireMonkey.
        Leia um procedimento geral para a migração de uma aplicação de VCL para FireMonkey na migração de aplicativos VCL para múltiplos dispositivos.
        Obter um programa VCL-to-FireMonkey conversor em http://www.midaconverter.com/.

**Três grandes bibliotecas são fornecidos pela RAD Studio:**

FireMonkey (FMX) é uma biblioteca de componentes visuais com gráficos sofisticados, animação e capacidades de estilo. Você pode criar aplicações FireMonkey para qualquer plataforma de destino suportados.

Biblioteca de Componentes Visuais (VCL) é uma hierarquia de objetos de componentes visuais que são suportados apenas no Windows (em aplicações Win32 e Win64).

Run-Time Library (RTL) é uma biblioteca processual compartilhada por Delphi e C ++ para qualquer plataforma de destino suportados. A RTL é composta por membros dos sistema, System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils e System.Classes unidades.

Você pode usar livremente a RTL em um aplicativo FireMonkey, mas você não pode usar diretamente o VCL em um módulo de aplicação FireMonkey.

[Fonte](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/FireMonkey_Application_Platform)